# How can I generate multiple Jenkins artifacts and zip them together?

Tags: maven, jenkins, zip, artifact

I'm using Jenkins to generate a war file, which so far, works, but I need to grab this war file and zip it together with some script files located in the project's workspace.

I'm really new with Jenkins and don't know how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Create a post build step in your Jenkins job and run the zip command.

Comment: Why not using maven-assembly-plugin for that?